# Xcode 7 autocompletion predictive text always shows OS X instead of iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, autocomplete, xcode7

I have a project that has both a iOS target and a OS X target. Some source files are strictly based on target and some are mixed with conditional compiles. Everything works and compiles fine, but at some point, Xcode started always predicting OS X classes instead of iOS classes.

It used to be that when my current target was iOS, it would predict iOS and vice versa, which would make sense. Now it seems to be stuck in OS X.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by predicting? Are you talking about your preprocessor conditions? If so, what are you using to differentiate between iOS and OS X?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant predictive text. Example: if I type an init function for a custom UIView, it shows NSRect instead of CGRect.

Comment: having the opposite problem, autocomplete showing iOS instead of OSX